# Magento 2 : Unable to create product on magento 2 store using rest api

Tags: magento2, product, api, rest-api

```
{message: "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",…}
message
:
"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources"
parameters
:
{resources: "Magento_Catalog::products"}
resources
:
"Magento_Catalog::products"
```

- Already Checked: Token is ok for admin
- Already Checked: Bearer token with space
- Already Checked: All access Allowed from admin panel As Admin

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin > System > Extensions > Integrations and create a new integration and use token id from here.

PHP code example to fetch / create / update magento 2 product will all attribute and image data

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$token = 'upp1cde4igj33bfx0aunlj0vn5vjf2a1';
$m2 = "http://localhost/M2/ce/magento217ce_1";

//get product data
/*$ch = curl_init($m2."/index.php/rest/all/V1/products/SIMPLE-101");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer ". $token));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, 1);
$error = curl_error($ch);
echo $error;
print_r($result);
*/

// create/update product
// media images
$path = "/var/www/html/M2/ce/magento217ce_1/pub/media/catalog/product/m/b/mb02-gray-0.jpg";
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$mediaName1 = "mb02-gray-0.jpg";
$type1 = mime_content_type($path);
$base64Media1 = base64_encode($data);

$path = "/var/www/html/M2/ce/magento217ce_1/pub/media/catalog/product/m/b/mb02-blue-0.jpg";
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$mediaName2 = "mb02-blue-0.jpg";
$type2 = mime_content_type($path);
$base64Media2 = base64_encode($data);

$data =
[
    "sku" => "02-682-557",
    "name" => "Fisherbrand Free-Standing Microcentrifuge Tubes with Screw Caps",
    "attribute_set_id" => 4,
    "price" => 34,
    "status" => 1,
    "visibility" => 4,
    "type_id" => "simple",
    "weight" => 1,
    "extension_attributes" => 
        [
            "stock_item" => 
                [
                    "qty" => 100, 
                    "is_in_stock" => 1,
                    "is_qty_decimal" => "",
                    "show_default_notification_message" => "",
                    "use_config_min_qty" => 1,
                    "min_qty" => 0,
                    "use_config_min_sale_qty" => 1,
                    "min_sale_qty" => 1,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty" => 1,
                    "max_sale_qty" => 10000,
                    "use_config_backorders" => 1,
                    "backorders" => 0,
                    "use_config_notify_stock_qty" => 1,
                    "notify_stock_qty" => 1,
                    "use_config_qty_increments" => 1,
                    "qty_increments" => 0,
                    "use_config_enable_qty_inc" => 1,
                    "enable_qty_increments" => 0,
                    "use_config_manage_stock" => 1,
                    "manage_stock" => 0,
                    "low_stock_date" => "",
                    "is_decimal_divided" => "",
                    "stock_status_changed_auto" => 0,
                ],
        ],
    "product_links" =>
        [
            [
                "sku" => "02-682-557",
                "link_type" => "related",
                "linked_product_sku" => "24-WG087",
                "linkedProductType" => "simple",
                "position" => 1,
                "extension_attributes" => [],
            ],
            [
                "sku" => "02-682-557",
                "link_type" => "related",
                "linked_product_sku" => "24-WG086",
                "linked_product_type" => "simple",
                "position" => 2,
                "extension_attributes" => [],
            ],
            [
                "sku" => "02-682-557",
                "link_type" => "crosssell",
                "linked_product_sku" => "24-WG087",
                "linked_product_type" => "simple",
                "position" => 1,
                "extension_attributes" => [],
            ],
            [
                "sku" => "02-682-557",
                "link_type" => "crosssell",
                "linked_product_sku" => "24-WG086",
                "linked_product_type" => "simple",
                "position" => 2,
                "extension_attributes" => [],
            ],
            [
                "sku" => "02-682-557",
                "link_type" => "upsell",
                "linked_product_sku" => "24-WG087",
                "linked_product_type" => "simple",
                "position" => 1,
                "extension_attributes" => [],
            ],
            [
                "sku" => "02-682-557",
                "link_type" => "upsell",
                "linked_product_sku" => "24-WG086",
                "linked_product_type" => "simple",
                "position" => 2,
                "extension_attributes" => [],
            ],
        ],
    "tier_prices" =>
        [
            [
                "customer_group_id" => 32000,
                "qty" => 10,
                "value" => 28,
            ],
            [
                "customer_group_id" => 32000,
                "qty" => 25,
                "value" => 27,
            ],
            [
                "customer_group_id" => 32000,
                "qty" => 50,
                "value" => 25,
            ],
        ],
    "options" =>
        [
            [
                "product_sku" => "02-682-557",
                //"option_id" => 1, // use while update
                "title" => "Custom Yoga Option",
                "type" => "drop_down",
                "sort_order" => 1,
                "is_require" => 0,
                "max_characters" => 0,
                "image_size_x" => 0,
                "image_size_y" => 0,
                "values" =>
                    [
                        [
                            "title" => "Gold",
                            "sort_order" => 1,
                            "price" => 10,
                            "price_type" => "fixed",
                            //"option_type_id" => 1, // use while update
                        ],
                        [
                            "title" => "Silver",
                            "sort_order" => 2,
                            "price" => 10,
                            "price_type" => "fixed",
                            //"option_type_id" => 2, // use while update
                        ],
                        [
                            "title" => "Platinum",
                            "sort_order" => 3,
                            "price" => 10,
                            "price_type" => "fixed",
                            //"option_type_id" => 3, // use while update
                        ],
                    ],

            ],
        ],
    "media_gallery_entries" =>
        [
            [
                "media_type" => "image",
                "label" => "Image",
                "position" => 1,
                "disabled" => false,
                "types" => ["image", "small_image", "thumbnail"],
                "content" =>
                [
                    "base64_encoded_data" => $base64Media1,
                    "type" => $type1 ,
                    "name"=> $mediaName1,
                ],
            ],
            [
                "media_type" => "image",
                "label" => "Image",
                "position" => 2,
                "disabled" => false,
                "types" => [],
                "content" =>
                [
                    "base64_encoded_data" => $base64Media2,
                    "type" => $type2 ,
                    "name"=> $mediaName2,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    "custom_attributes" => 
        [
            [
                "attribute_code" => "description",
                "value" => "Capacity: 1.5mL",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code" => "short_description",
                "value" => "Fisherbrand Free-Standing Microcentrifuge Tubes with Screw Caps",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "special_price",
                "value"=> 29.0000,
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "special_from_date",
                "value"=> "2017-11-01 00:00:00",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "special_to_date",
                "value"=> "2017-11-30 00:00:00",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "cost",
                "value"=> 19.0000,
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "meta_title",
                "value"=> "Meta Title",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "meta_keyword",
                "value"=> "meta1, meta2, meta3",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "meta_description",
                "value"=> "meta description",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "news_from_date",
                "value"=> "2017-11-01 00:00:00",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "news_to_date",
                "value"=> "2017-11-30 00:00:00",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code" => "category_ids",
                "value" => [3, 4],
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "country_of_manufacture",
                "value"=> "AL",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "url_key",
                "value"=> "fisherbrand-free-standing-microcentrifuge-tubes-with-screw-caps",
            ],
            [
                "attribute_code"=> "tax_class_id",
                "value"=> 2,
            ],
        ],
];

// create / update products data
$ch = curl_init($m2."/index.php/rest/all/V1/products/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(["product" => $data]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer ". $token));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, 1);
$error = curl_error($ch);
echo $error;
print_r($result);


// assign created product into a website
$websiteLinkData = [
    "sku" => "02-682-557",
    "website_id" => 1,
];

$ch = curl_init($m2."/index.php/rest/all/V1/products/02-682-557/websites/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(["product_website_link" => $websiteLinkData]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer ". $token));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, 1);
$error = curl_error($ch);
echo $error;
print_r($result);
```